# bitmap image wont able to show in android notification?

Tags: android

I want to display bitmap image as notification but below code is not working where i am going wrong i wont able to find i am getting image from url in bitmap form but cant able to display.

I am getting the bitmap image in the NotiIcon variable which of type bitmap. i have added getting bitmap image .

Thanks in advance .

```
public static void ShowNotification()
{    
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> t = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){  
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... p) {
            String NS =  Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

            /*  String dtitle = Title;
            String dbody = body; */

            Intent notificationIntent1 =new Intent(appContext, ChromeTestActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, 0, notificationIntent1, 0);
            NotificationManager mNm = (NotificationManager)   appContext.getSystemService(NS);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(appContext);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent1).setLargeIcon(NotiIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setContentTitle(Title)
                    .setContentText(body);
            Notification n = builder.getNotification();
            mNm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
            textTitle.setText(Title);
            textBody.setText(body);
            textTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Inside NotificationUIManager handleButtonClick");
                }
            });

            textBody.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Inside NotificationUIManager handleButtonClick");
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    };
    t.execute();
}

public static Bitmap DecodeIconUrl(String paramString1)
{
    NotiIcon = null;  
    try
    {
        URL iconurl =  new URL(paramString1);
        URLConnection conn =  iconurl.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis =  new BufferedInputStream(is);
        NotiIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){

    }
return NotiIcon;
}
```

Comment: Follow this link.... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

we have to add Icon to the Notifications like this

check this

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notify_icon, "Name", when);

notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Title", "contentText", contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(ID, notification);
```